# Assembly 64-bit Integral algorithm

Tags: assembly, x86, integral

I've written myself a function in C that computes an integral in given number of steps:

```
double integr(double start, double end, unsigned int steps){
    double integral = 0,
            currentStep = start;
    double step = (end-start)/steps,
            halfStep = 1/2*step;

    while(currentStep <= end){
            integral += 1/(currentStep+halfStep)*step;
            currentStep += step;
    }

    return integral;
}
```

Then I have decompiled it with gcc and that's what I've been left with:

```
.global integr
integr:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp

    movsd   %xmm0, -40(%rbp)
    movsd   %xmm1, -48(%rbp)
    movl    %edi, -52(%rbp)
    movl    $0, %eax
    movq    %rax, -32(%rbp)

    movq    -40(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, -24(%rbp)

    movsd   -48(%rbp), %xmm0
    movapd  %xmm0, %xmm1
    subsd   -40(%rbp), %xmm1
    movl    -52(%rbp), %eax

    testq   %rax, %rax
    js      .L2

    cvtsi2sdq       %rax, %xmm0
    jmp     .L3
.L2:
        #
        movq    %rax, %rdx
        shrq    %rdx
        andl    $1, %eax
        orq     %rax, %rdx
        cvtsi2sdq       %rdx, %xmm0
        addsd   %xmm0, %xmm0
.L3:
    divsd   %xmm0, %xmm1
    movapd  %xmm1, %xmm0
    movsd   %xmm0, -16(%rbp)
    movsd   -16(%rbp), %xmm1
    xorpd   %xmm0, %xmm0
    mulsd   %xmm1, %xmm0
    movsd   %xmm0, -8(%rbp)
    jmp     .L4
.L5:
    movsd   -24(%rbp), %xmm0
    addsd   -8(%rbp), %xmm0
    movsd   .LC1(%rip), %xmm1
    divsd   %xmm0, %xmm1
    movapd  %xmm1, %xmm0
    mulsd   -16(%rbp), %xmm0
    movsd   -32(%rbp), %xmm1
    addsd   %xmm1, %xmm0
    movsd   %xmm0, -32(%rbp)
    movsd   -24(%rbp), %xmm0
    addsd   -16(%rbp), %xmm0
    movsd   %xmm0, -24(%rbp)
.L4:
    movsd   -48(%rbp), %xmm0
    ucomisd -24(%rbp), %xmm0
    jae     .L5
    movq    -32(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, -64(%rbp)
    movsd   -64(%rbp), %xmm0
    popq    %rbp
    ret
.LC1:
    .long   0
    .long   1072693248
```

I know that first and second line are pushing old stack pointer and moving a new one. Couple next lines are fetching parameters (start, end, steps) and moving them onto stack.

Testq as far as I know is giving us an information if %rax < 0.

I can't find out what the other lines are for though.
Please help me

Comment: Don't waste your time with `-O0` compiler output.  It's full of extra stores and reloads to memory.  `gcc -O3 -ffast-math -fverbose-asm` makes nice easy-to-read output for this function, [have a look on the godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/2uvs6L).

Comment: See the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for links to Intel's insn set reference guide, and lots of other links.  You might want to learn Intel syntax, instead of AT&T syntax, first, since the Intel manuals use Intel syntax.

Comment: Thanks. Still I only understand a little of that output.
Will it work with just as little code though? It is required for me to use AT&T syntax.

Comment: Do you know what `halfStep = 1/2*step;` does? Is it what you want?

Comment: @Fryzjer: What are you trying to accomplish?  Why is AT&T syntax required?  Are you planning to contribute some code to a project that already uses AT&T syntax for asm?  Is there a question here besides "explain this code to me"?  Because if not, this isn't a good fit for the SO Q&A format.

Comment: @KerrekSB, I've written that code, and I know what it does, there's no need for any sarcasm here.

Comment: @PeterCordes It is required because my course does so. I'm sorry for that kind of question though. (Decompiled your way) function seems to work just as good as the one written in C, so thank you for that. I think I'll find out myself meaning of these lines. Thanks yet again ;)